# are there any decent-sized open source projects using eclipse EMF and ecore?

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

that have source code available?

and follow good EMF recommended design principles.

Comment: Did you find one that matches what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely:

- The GMF project of Eclipse uses EMF extensively.
- The UML modelling project of Eclipse uses EMF + GMF.
- The implementation of XSD in Eclipse is also provided with an EMF implementation.

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of other open source projects with source code available that rely on EMF. One of my projects, [IAML](http://openiaml.org), is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Mule uses it for their Mule IDE product:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULEIDE/Home

Source code here:
http://svn.muleforge.org/mule-ide/trunk/src/main/